# Recurring tasks with Python's MRQ library

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, task-queue

["MRQ is a distributed task queue for python built on top of mongo, redis and gevent."](http://mrq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) Even though it states `/!\ MRQ is not yet ready for public use. Soon!` on the front page of the documentation, it already looks pretty nifty and I managed to use the basic features following the `Getting Started` docs.

However, what I do not yet understand is how I can schedule recurring tasks, e.g. scheduling a job to run every 5 minutes (similar to [Celery Beat](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) or [rq-scheduler](https://github.com/ui/rq-scheduler) or [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)). Unfortunately, the documentation [is only pointing to the unit tests](http://mrq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/recurring-jobs/) on this feature (while stating that there is something like a scheduler available) but I could not figure out from the test code how it works.

Are there any code snippets with examples available or did anybody already achieve to try this out?

Answer (score 1):

To get you started,

Add a schedule to a config file like [this](http://mrq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/jobs-maintenance/). Then use the interval to set frequency (you can also use time-of-day, not sure how yet).

Use the scheduler api to requeue out-of-data tasks.

```
import mrq.scheduler
from mongodb.mongo_client import MongoCLient 

db = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
collection = db.mrq.mrq_scheduled_jobs

task = mrq.scheduler.Schedule(collection)
task.refresh()  ## read mongodb database
task.check()  ## Queues out-of-date tasks
```

I haven't seen any clear examples on how to do this properly yet.